# How to remember a mount point

Tags: linux, mount, automount, disk-volume

I am using Red Hat Enterprise 6.3 and I have just mounted a new volume in one folder of my preference.

After reboot that mount point was lost and the volume was mounted at his original place.

In which place I can set my `mount` call so that I can have my volume always at the same place? Do I have to look at init.d or is there a better place?

Comment: /etc/fstab is the file where you should add all your mounts so that after reboot it gets mounted again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`/etc/fstab` is the traditional configuration file to define permanent mounts.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating more on the [@NickW's solution](https://serverfault.com/a/510321/1036394), a general way to add a new entry to the `/etc/fstab` file is the following:

1. check the UUID of your device with `blkid` command:

```bash
sudo blkid
```

Output should be of the following type:

```bash
...
/dev/<DEVICE>: UUID="<DEVICE-UUID>" ...
...
```

2. Knowing the UUID of a device, append a new entry to the bottom of `/etc/fstab` file, (**followed by a new line**, to avoid warnings):

```bash
# /dev/<DEVICE>  <-- comment to identify what you mounted
UUID=<DEVICE-UUID>    <MOUNT-POINT>   auto    defaults    0    0
```

3. **Double check `/etc/fstab` !** In case of a mistake you would have to **recover your system!**
4. Reboot ensured that everything is fine :)